# Execute Reactive Rules using Drools

Tags: java, drools

*(I am a bit new to working with Drools, so please excuse if this is a simple question).*

I would like to use Drools for reactive execution of rules, this means we could consider the “facts” being inserted to be “event” instances. However, I want this to execute in a way that rules can be fired as soon as events are received. But, in the case that a rule may depend on several events, how can I configure the Working Memory, to remember previous events. Consider a very simple example:

Say I have the following rules:

```
 - when (E1) do A1
 - when (E2) do A2
 - when (E1,E2) do A3
```

Then, if time progresses as follows, I want to following rules to be fired, example:

```
 - t=1 , E1 happens => A1 fired
 - t=2 , E2 happens => A2 fired + A3 fired
```

The problem I have is if I call `ksession.fireAllRules()` after every insertion, the working memory will forget all previous events. What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as you use a [Stateful Knowledge Session](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch02.html#d0e737), what you are probably doing because the stateless one has no fireAllRules() method, the WM will *not* forget all the inserted facts.

What you express as "E1 happens" should be ksession.insert(E1);

You may play with the example given in the documentation (link above)...

Comment: Thanks pgras, I’ve fixed my code now. Although I am trying to understand now, how does the rule engine know not to re-fire the rules that it already matched? Since the facts remain in WM. If this happens to be explained in any docs, would be helpful to read...

Comment: Yes, that's explained in the docs. The rules are activated by the set of facts, when a set of facts that matches with the rule condition are inserted the activation is created and then fired (on the fireAllRules()). After that, if you modify one of your facts and notify the engine (ksession.modify/update) the activation will be recreated and the rule can be re fired. If you don't change your fact the rule will be activated and fired just once for that combination of facts.